# How to bind my activity when a contact entry data, such as birthday is clicked?

Tags: android

How can I bind my application so, when the Birthday entry is clicked on a Contact Entry, it will open up my activity?

[Birthday http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/7673/screenbirthday.png](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/7673/screenbirthday.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to do that.